# UnsupportedOperationException while iterating over CopyOnWriteArrayList

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, iterator, copyonwritearraylist

I came across the following statement in a book:

> Any mutating methods called on a copy-on-write-based `Iterator` or `ListIterator` (such as add, set or remove) will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

But when I run the following code, it works just fine and doesn't throw the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 3, 52));
System.out.println("Before " + list);
for (Integer item : list) {
    System.out.println(item + " ");
    list.remove(item);
}
System.out.println("After " + list);
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
Before [4, 3, 52]
4 
3 
52 
After []
```

Why am I not getting the exception while I am modifying the given `list` using the `remove` method?

Comment: You're never calling any method on an Iterator or ListIterator.

Comment: You are calling `remove` on the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, not on an iterator as the text you quoted mentions. And it's `UnsupportedOperationException`, not `UpsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `remove` **on the list itself**, which is fine. The documentation states that calling `remove` **on the list's iterator** would throw an `UpsupportedOperationException`. E.g.:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Integer item = iter.next(); 
    System.out.println(item + " ");
    iter.remove(); // Will throw an UnsupportedOperationException
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks good with Mureinik's answer. However, if you deep dive into this -

**If using `ArrayList`**

- Use `for` loop and list `remove(current_index)` method, it works fine.

And with `iterator` approach -

- Use iterator `remove()` method instead of list `remove()`, it works fine
- Throws `ConcurrentModificationException` if use list `remove()` method

**If in multi-threaded environment -**

Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

- With list `remove(current_element)` it works fine
- With `Iterator` or `ListIterator` `remove()` method, it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`

Take a look at below example -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class AvoidCMEExample {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<>();  
       listOfBooks.add("Programming Pearls");
       listOfBooks.add("Clean Code");
       listOfBooks.add("Effective Java");
       listOfBooks.add("Code Complete");
       System.out.println("List before : " + listOfBooks);
       /*for(int i=0; i<listOfBooks.size(); i++){
           String book = listOfBooks.get(i);
           if(book.contains("Programming")){
               System.out.println("Removing " + book);
               listOfBooks.remove(i); // works fine
           }
       }*/
       Iterator<String> itr = listOfBooks.iterator();
       while(itr.hasNext()){
            String book = itr.next();
            if(book.contains("Programming")){
               System.out.println("Removing " + book);
               //listOfBooks.remove(book); // will throw CME
               itr.remove(); // using iterator remove(), it works fine
           }
       }
       System.out.println("List after : " + listOfBooks);
       
       List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); 
       list.add("B"); list.add("W"); list.add("Q"); list.add("S");
       System.out.println("\n\nList before : " + list);
       Iterator<String> itr1 = list.iterator();
       while(itr1.hasNext()){
            String book = itr1.next();
            if(book.contains("Q")){
               System.out.println("Removing " + book);
               list.remove(book); // works fine on list object remove()
               itr1.remove(); // throws UnsupportedOperationException on iterator, ListIterator obj
           }
       }
       System.out.println("List after : " + list);       
   }
}
```